# Mapping between AssetTypes and DomainTypes in Collibra

Tags: metadata, collibra

From Collibra Documentation (https://university.collibra.com/knowledge/collibra-body-of-knowledge/data-governance-operating-model/organizational-concepts/domain-types/)

> A Domain Type formally defines which types of Assets can be created in the Domain. In other words it serves as a template. By assigning asset types to a domain type, you can specify which asset types can be created within which domain type.

Is there any such strict mapping in place? Can a user create a mapping between domain type and asset type? Is there any way, through REST APIs / Java Connectors, that these mappings can be createt or retrived?

Answer (score 0):

In Collibra certain domain type has a certain asset type under it. This means from one domain is a physical dictionary then you can have Column Asset, Code and code number asset and etc. To create a separate mapping, you need to have System admin rights. If you do then the first step is to go to setting —> Domain type -> Select the domain type you want to map —> go to characteristics in that domain —> then check Mark on whichever asset type you want to map.

The second step is to create a relationship between that domain and assets if you want to retrieve any data or hierarchy. You can create relationships from setting only where you also need system admin's rights.
Let me know if you have any follow up on this.
(Share a screenshot or details if still has query)